# fusermount call similar to mount --bind for local directories?

Tags: bind, ubuntu-12.04, local, mount

Is there a  way to bind one directory to another via `fusermount`, specifically for Ubuntu?
I would like to avoid using just `mount` so that `sudo` is not needed, and I would also like to avoid the need to compile extra driver types (I'm hoping that binding a directory is a standard type).

Here are my hit-and-miss attempts:

```
$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS \n \l
$ fusermount --version
fusermount version: 2.8.6
$ ls
src
$ fusermount ~+/src ~+/dest
fusermount: extra arguments after the mountpoint
$ fusermount -o -t none ~+/src ~+/dest
fusermount: extra arguments after the mountpoint
$ fusermount -o -t rw ~+/src ~+/dest
fusermount: extra arguments after the mountpoint
$ fusermount -o -t bind ~+/src ~+/dest
fusermount: extra arguments after the mountpoint
$ fusermount -o --bind ~+/src ~+/dest
fusermount: extra arguments after the mountpoint
$ fusermount --bind ~+/src ~+/dest
fusermount: unrecognized option '--bind'
```

The following worked for `mount --bind` (had to create directory first)

```
$ sudo mount --bind ~+/src ~+/dest
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, came back to this question, Googled, saw the FUSE manual, this post, then [`bindfs`](http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/partel/bindfs_docs/bindfs.1.html) which does exactly what I had wanted.

This usage worked for me:

```
bindfs -n ~+/src ~+/dest
```

Without `-n, --no-allow-other`, then FUSE gave me an error:

```
fusermount: failed to open /etc/fuse.conf: Permission denied
fusermount: option allow_other only allowed if 'user_allow_other' is set in /etc/fuse.conf
```

Odd that it wants to allow other users by default.

It's available in Ubuntu 12.04,

```
sudo apt-get install bindfs
```